# Changing Data Source from one data lake to another

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I'm migrating a DW that has external tables, however they point to the original data lake instead of the copy I created. Is there any easy/efficient way to repoint the data source without having to drop/recreate all the external tables? I found that the ALTER EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE is only compatible with SQL Server 2016.

Any insights are appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting and recreating external definitions is currently the only method supported for Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

Assuming that your credentials have not changed, you'll have to follow this sequence:

- Drop external tables
- Drop external data source
- Create external data source
- Create external tables

How are you loading your DW? You might avoid this problem if you're using the Azure SQL Data Warehouse loaders from ADF V2 or Databricks. These components create and drop their external definitions for each run.

The one feature you'll lose from the ADF / Databricks approach is if you're using views over external tables to add metadata such as load datetime, hashes, etc., at the point of ingestion.

I've just created a request for this feature, please add your vote and supporting comments.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/35957506-alter-external-data-source

Comment: Thanks for this, we solved the problem by doing exactly this.